# How do I enter multiple timestamps for multiple columns as they are modified?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was able to modify if in any column within column 1 through 9 was modified the time stamp was entered on column 10 and last modified on column 11.

I know need to get granular and timestamp when each column is first modified, while maintaining the existing timestamp setting.

I believe this is as simple as an "if" statement but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is what I have so far. This gives me the date and time any cell, between column 1 and 9 is first modified, on that row and returns date and time on column 10, then last modified date and time on column 11 if any changes are done.
Now i want to keep record of when column 1-9 are first modified as well, and enter them on the same sheet starting at column 12

```
function addTimestamp (e){
 //variables
 var startRow = 2;
 var ws = "Daily Log"
 var currentDate = 1

 //get modified row and column
 var row = e.range.getRow();
 var col = e.range.getColumn();

 if(([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].includes(col))&& row >= startRow 
 &&e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() ==ws){

  var currentDate = new Date();
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 11).setValue(currentDate);
  if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 10).getValue()== ""){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,10).setValue(currentDate);
  } // END IF check if date created exists
 } // END IF column, row, worksheet
}
```

Special thanks to @raygun who helped me in creating uniq driver IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation:

Your goal is:

- Keep the datetime for which any cell in columns 1-9  is modified for the first time in column 10.
- For every cell modified in columns 1-9 add a last modified stamp in columns 12-20 **respectively**. For example if column 1 is modified, update timestamp in column 12, if column 2 is modified update column 13 etc.

For performance reasons, it is always a good practice to store the code you are using often, in variables:

- For example `e.source.getActiveSheet()` is used 4 times in your code and every time it is called, it consumes resources. You can instead store it in a variable and use that variable instead.

### Solution:

```
function addTimestamp (e){
 //variables
 const startRow = 2;
 const ws = "Daily Log"
 //get modified row and column
 const rng = e.range;
 const as = rng.getSheet();
 const row = rng.getRow();
 const col = rng.getColumn();
  
 if(col>=1 && col<=9&& row >= startRow && as.getName() ==ws){
  const currentDate = new Date();
  const rng_all = as.getRange(row, col+11);
  const rng_ten = as.getRange(row, 10);
  as.getRange(row,11).setValue(currentDate);
  if(rng_all.getValue()== ""){
      rng_all.setValue(currentDate)
   }
  if(rng_ten.getValue()== ""){
      rng_ten.setValue(currentDate);
  } 
 } 
}
```

**Side Note:**

You don't need an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) trigger for this particular task. You can replace `addTimestamp(e)` with `onEdit(e)` ([simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)) and it would also work. But it is up to you what you prefer, but it would be a good idea to read the differences (in the hyperlinks I provided).

Comment: I have my script starting with onEdit(e) following with addTimestamp and adding  a uniq ID to column 4. I actually only want to record the first time a cell modified in columns 1-9.  add modified stamp in columns 12-20 respectively. For example if column 1 is modified, update timestamp in column 12, if column 2 is modified update column 13 etc. I don't want it to change after that.

Comment: @JaimeQuintero I updated my answer. Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: how do i change the date and time format to show am and pm instead?

Comment: i just noticed on col 11 i had the "last modified date and time" for changes on any col between 1 and 9. It's no longer working

Comment: @JaimeQuintero you can do that programmatically but I think it makes more sense to change the format in the sheet itself. Select the full columns and go to `Format => Number => Date time`

Comment: `i just noticed on col 11 i had the "last modified date and time" for changes on any col between 1 and 9. It's no longer working` I updated my answer. Check it out again. @JaimeQuintero

Comment: again, this worked perfectly. I'm taking some JavaScript classes now to better understand this. Truly appreciate the help this community provides

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function for logging all of your changes into a file:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('entry');
  let sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart < 10) {
    let f = DriveApp.getFileById('file id');
    let c = f.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    let ts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    let o = c + ts + ',' + sh.getName() + ',' + e.range.rowStart + ',' + e.range.columnStart + ',' + e.oldValue + ',' + e.value + ',' + e.user.getEmail() + '\r\n';
    f.setContent(o);
    Logger.log(o);
  }
}
```

Requires Installable Trigger

Data Table:

| timestamp | sheetname | row | col | oldvalue | value | useremail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sat Feb 13 2021 08:53:53 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | Sheet1 | 5 | 4 | 30 | 55 | Redacted |
| Sat Feb 13 2021 08:54:58 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | Sheet1 | 9 | 4 | 32 | 55 | Redacted |
| Sat Feb 13 2021 08:56:05 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | Sheet1 | 14 | 7 | 62 | new value | Redacted |
| Sat Feb 13 2021 08:56:45 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | Sheet1 | 1 | 2 | 10 | 45 | Redacted |
| Sat Feb 13 2021 08:56:52 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | Sheet1 | 3 | 2 | 11 | 77 | Redacted |
| Sat Feb 13 2021 09:10:16 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | Sheet2 | 5 | 2 | 4 | 77 | Redacted |
| Sat Feb 13 2021 09:16:08 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | Sheet5 | 8 | 4 | undefined | 666 | Redacted |
| Sat Feb 13 2021 09:18:04 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | Sheet5 | 13 | 7 | undefined | 66 | Redacted |
| Sat Feb 13 2021 09:19:44 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | Sheet5 | 9 | 3 | undefined | 66 | Redacted |
| Sat Feb 13 2021 09:20:29 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | Sheet5 | 11 | 7 | undefined | kk | Redacted |
| Sat Feb 13 2021 09:22:21 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | Sheet1 | 1 | 1 | undefined | undefined | Redacted |

Here's a utility for loading a simple csv into a spreadsheet:

```
function loadCSVintoSpreadsheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const resp1 = ui.prompt('Select Sheet Name', 'Enter destination sheet name', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (resp1.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK && resp1.getResponseText().length > 0) {
    const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    sh.clearContents();
    const resp2 = ui.prompt('CSV FileId', 'Enter file id of csv', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    if (resp2.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK && resp2.getResponseText().length > 0) {
      const file = DriveApp.getFileById(resp2.getResponseText());
      const csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
      let csvA = Utilities.parseCsv(csv)
      sh.getRange(1, 1, csvA.length, csvA[0].length).setValues(csvA);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @cooper this is good to know also, however I need the time stamp to display on the actual sheet for compliance reasons.